# Antonym of verb “holster”

Tags: antonyms

What is a word that means to remove from a holster as opposed to putting something back in a holster? I’ve searched *deholster* and *unholster*, each with no results found.

Comment: What search engine are you using?  Google.com gives "about 120,000" results for *unholster*.  Granted, this isn't a very big number by Google standards, but it's enough that I wouldn't dismiss all of these uses as errors.  Plenty of them look perfectly credible to me.

Comment: I used dictionary.com

I didn't use Google due to the potential for it to crawl a page where someone used an incorrect term for the lack of a more suitable word.

Comment: A better starting point is OneLook.com, which provides links to entries in many reputable references. (It's significant that OneLook.com found no reputable references to cite for *unholster*.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You’re probably thinking of *draw*[¹](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/draw#Verb), which is certainly used with this meaning:

> To pull out (as a gun from a holster, or a tooth).

For example, you might say “the gunslinger *drew* his pistol”.

Comment: Again, I don't like sounding like an ass, but "to draw a gun" has nothing to do with a holster. Have you ever seen anyone draw a shotgun from a holster? I doubt that. Being too technical I can safely claim that you're missing the point here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the objection. I can find many instances in COCA, for example, with *gun* or *pistol* and *draw*, and just a few where these are with *unholster*. I can't find instances where a *shotgun* is unholstered, and in a quick search, only a few examples of a *shotgun*, *rifle*, etc. with *draw*, which makes sense to me because these are carried differently. I think people tend to associate *draw* with removing a weapon - perhaps a canonical six-shooter - from a holster.

Comment: @Rimmer, I certainly have seen a shotgun get drawn from a holster.  (It is a much larger holster and commonly is mounted on a horse in order to be convenient to the rider.)  So I have to disagree with your objection; drawing a gun is most definitely a 'remove-from-holster' action.  (Also I have to agree with aedia that it's rare to say "he drew a shotgun" because shotguns aren't normally kept in a holster; but it's also possible that someone could "draw a shotgun" simply by removing it from its normal stored position on a gunrack, for example.)

Comment: While I agree with RiMMER that the *most precise* antonym of *holster* is *unholster*, I still think *draw* is a useful answer because it is a suitable antonym in most of the situations you'd find yourself using *holster* in the first place.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, it is *unholster*. I’m sure of it, because I’ve heard it a lot in those thousands of movies I’ve seen in my life.

Check the “unholster” *Wiktionary* entry[¹](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unholster) for further info.

Answer (score 11):

I would use the term *draw*, as in “He drew his gun to confront the robbers, then holstered it after they ran away.”

A dictionary entry and example from *TheFreeDictionary*:

> To take or pull out: *drew a gun from beneath the counter*; *drew out a fat wallet*.[¹](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/draw)

Comment: Actually, as you even quoted, "to draw a gun" means to take it from any place and prepare to fire. It's far from being an antonym to "holster."

Comment: Perhaps directly, but I would never use the term "unholster" in spoken English and I have never heard the term used.  My body of watching westerns, however, has heard "draw" more times than I can remember :)

Comment: Well, don't you think that you can unholster a gun to clean it? You don't necessarily draw it and shoot. You just unholster, clean it and holster it back :)

Comment: That's a fair point, but most of the time if you were discussing cleaning a gun, the removal from the holster would likely be omitted.  More context is needed, however, from the original question.

Comment: I think the video game Mass Effect used the term "unholster" (IIRC the "H" key could holster and unholster), I'd have to check the manual when I get home to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest that *draw* and *unholster* are subtly different- to draw a firearm is to remove it from the holster with intent to use it (or at least threaten such use); unholster would be more commonly used when surrendering or relinquishing a weapon, either for reasons of military discipline or to return to stores when no longer required.

Comment: I think this is the key distinction, and it’s one of body language and intent. When I hear *unholster*, I infer the gunman’s finger is not on the trigger, and the safety may even be on. When I hear *draw*, I infer the gunman’s finger is on the trigger, the safety is off, and he may even be aiming. It’s similar to *unsheathe* versus *draw* for a sword or knife.

Answer (score 0):

I was drawn here because I am writing a story where an officer is shot before he has a chance to "unholster" his gun. Dictionary.com does not recognize this word, and I don't want to use the word "draw" for purely artistic reasons. I thought I had heard the word "unholster" as well. What is a reasonable antonym, other than "draw?" Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Your answer has already been posted by another user and doesn't provide any additional information. Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.